# What is the minimal number of vertices a graph not distance-embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can have?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, metric-spaces, extremal-combinatorics

Suppose $\Gamma(V, E)$ is a graph, and $(M, \rho)$ is a metric space. Let's call a function $h: V \to M$ distance-embedding if it satisfies the property "$(v, u) \in E$ iff $\rho(h(v), h(u))=1$". Let's call $\Gamma(V, E)$ distance-embeddable in $(M, \rho)$, if one can construct a distance-embedding for it.

My question is:

> What is the minimal number $m(n)$ of vertices a graph not distance-embeddable in $(\mathbb{R}^n, l_2)$ can have?

According to the "The realization of distances within sets in Euclidean space" by Larman and Rogers the chromatic number of any graph distance embeddable in $(\mathbb{R}^n, l_q)$ (for some arbitrary $q \geq 1$) does not exceed $(3+o(1))^n$. Thus, $m(n) \leq (3+o(1))^n$ with the example being a complete graph.

However, I do not know, how to get any better bounds...

Comment: The graph formed by the vertices and edges of the $(n+1)$-simplex cannot be distance-embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So, we must have $m(n)\leq n+2$.